# Loop Select not working on MacBook M1 Pro - Blender 3.6.2

Tags: edges, osx, select, loop

I'm using a Blender 3.6.2 and while attempting to the loop select on a simple cube, it doesn't work.

I have tried several combinations of keys (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd>, <kbd>Double-Click</kbd>, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Double-Click</kbd>), nothing seems to work.

I have the 3 mouse wheel turned off. I have to use this loop select a lot and it's not working.

Comment: Hello could you please show a screenshot and highlight the edge loop you're trying to select?

Comment: When you say "a simple cube", do you mean a default cube consisting of 8 vertices and 6 faces? There is no edge loop on this cube.

Comment: Are you trying to **create** a loop cut  or select one (which as @GordonBrinkmann says won't exist on a simple cube)? The hotkey to create one is Ctrl-R or Command-R on a Mac.